# Swipe on ViewFlipper

Tags: android, listeners

I have a ViewFlipper and in it, four scrollviews with layouts in those.

I use the following code (for each scrollview) to swipe:

```
ScrollView View1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.View1);
    View1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                FirstX = (int) event.getX();
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                int LastX = (int) event.getX();

                if (FirstX - LastX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                } else if (LastX - FirstX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

It works, but it looks like if I swipe from View 1 to View 2, I see a views 2 and 3 mixed together and it finally shows view 4.

So it seems the OnTouchListeners for each view are called after eachother.
How can I prevent this from happening?

A short and fast swipe does what it is supposed to do.

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your code you have in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to get a swipe. Now, if you don't want swipe, and want to move the screen along with the finger, you should implement `ViewPager` as JafarKhQ just mentioned.

Comment: Changing from ACTION_MOVE to ACTION_UP did the trick.
Now I can swipe between the scrollviews without a problem.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the setOnTouchListener will called multible time (while you sliding your finger), so the

```
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
viewFlipper.showNext();
```

will called multiple time

i suggest you to use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead of ViewFlipper.

Comment: if your answer doesn't cover the question, please add it as a comment.

Comment: That kinds of puts me back to the beginning where nothing wanted to work. I was just so happy to actually be able to swipe between layouts.